# Update specific row in EfficientAdapter ListView Android

Tags: android, android-listview, listview-adapter

Util.class below contain a static ArrayList of maximum 2 int number.

```
public class Util extends Activity {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> selectedPosition= new ArrayList<Integer>();

  selectedPosition.add(3);
  selectedPosition.add(5);

}
```

In my getView() adapter method i attempt to change the textview and made an image visible for position 3 and 5 only. The problem is for the imageview only the last element is visible, I cannot show number 3 imageview.  How can i get both imageview visible inside the adapter. here is my getview method.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        vi = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vrow, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.one = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_one);
            holder.two = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_second);
            holder.three = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_num_compte);
            holder.image = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.single_image);
            holder.relative_layout = (RelativeLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.corner);

        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

        vi.setTag(holder);

        String stDebit =Util.decimalFloatForm(Float.valueOf((data.get(position).getSoldeCompte())));
        if (stDebit.startsWith(","))
            stDebit = "0 000"+stDebit;

        if (data.get(position).getAuthCompte().equalsIgnoreCase("N")){

            holder.one.setText(data.get(position).getLibelleCompte());
            holder.two.setText(stDebit+" EUR");
            holder.three.setText(vi.getResources().getString(R.string.special)+" "+data.get(position).getNumComtpe());          

        }else {

            holder.one.setText(data.get(position).getLibelleCompte());
            holder.two.setText("xx,xxx EUR");
            holder.three.setText(vi.getResources().getString(R.string.special)+" "+data.get(position).getNumComtpe());          
        }


        holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE); //hide right tick

        System.out.println("VirementEmmeteurSize : "+Util.selectedPosition.size());

        //check if selectedPosition is empty
        if (Util.selectedPosition!=null){


            for(int x=0;x<Util.selectedPosition.size();x++){

                int index = Util.selectedPosition.get(x).toString().indexOf(String.valueOf(position));
                boolean boolValue = (index == -1?false:true);

                if (boolValue){
                    holder.two.setText(stDebit+" "+data.get(position).getDeviseCompte());
                    holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //show right tick

                }else {
                    holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE); //hide right tick
                }
            }
        }




        return vi;
    }
```

Comment: i think instead of handle custom list for selection item just try to put one flag in your list item holder or your custom class for list item and base on this flag value try to hide/show image.

Comment: you want the whole custom adapter

Comment: please check my edited comment and also put you adapter whole code.

Comment: please check updated question i put whole adapter

Comment: Now just try to add one flag (boolean) in ComptePost for each list item default value is false and modify this value based on position of list item and try to shown image on this flag value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

1. Take one flag in ComptePost class

   ```
   private boolean isSelected;

   public void setIsSelected(boolean isSelected){
    this.isSelected=isSelected;
   }

   public boolean isSelected(){
    return isSelected;
   }
   ```
2. How to change selection value.

   ```
   data.get(3).setIsSelected(true);

   data.get(5).setIsSelected(true);
   ```
3. How to use selection value in adapter.

   ```
   if(data.get(position).isSelected()){
      holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }else{
      holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
   ```